# Change the color of C# String when displaying in a DataTable cell

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I am working in C# windows form application and I want to change color of string which I am displaying in a grid.

```
//dtRList is a DataTable  
dtRList.Rows.Add(something + "This should be red");
```

Basically I need to change the color of the string that I am appending here. Something like this,

```
String str = "This should be red";
```

now change the color of str to Red and

```
dtReconList.Rows.Add(something + str);
```

I do not think this is possible to do like this, may be i will have to go for a label or something. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The way you ask the question I tend to answer that you cannot change the color of a `string`; it has no color at all. If you want to display it in a different color, then you have to set properties on the control that you use to display it. In case of a `DataGridView` you can use the `DataGridViewCell.Style` for that, but you have to determine which color the string should be displayed in by analyzing it's content yourself (make/obey rules about formatting).

Comment: I agree with John. Maybe you should reconstruct your question. Even junior level programmer knows that the variable of type string or any type has no color. Coloring can be seen in the UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change to color of a string. Because it has no color to begin with, what you want, as you said, is to change the color of the component which represents your string value.

One quick code to give you a general idea, here's how you would set the color of a `DataGridViewCell`

```
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.ForeColor = Color.Red;

dgVenta.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style = style;
```

Of course you need to style the cell you want and not necessarily the first one. That's up to you. Keep in mind that if the row you changed is selected it may not reflect the color you set, to solve that look the `SelectionForeColor` property.

With all that you can, of course, change everything you need and do whatever conditional logic such as use green or red color if the value is positive or negative, for example.

Answer (score 5):

`DataTable` is not related to UI. It is not a control. It's just a data holder. Question would have sense if you would ask about `DataGridView` control or some other way of **displaying** data. But string is a sequence of characters. String holds text and nothing more. String has no knowledge of the way you will use it (e.g. display string).